# Passing Data between vue components

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, components, vue-component

I have 3 vue components, Component A uses an event listener to gather the data from the HTML text a user clicks on and stores it into a variable. Component B will take the data and make an API call to display in a table. Component C uses Component A to render a diagram and Component C will use Component B to render a table below the diagram.

Component A:

```
 mounted() {
      window.addEventListener('node_clicked', (e) => {this.nodeName = e.detail.name})
    },
      data() {
      return {
        nodeName: ''
      };
```

Question:

How can I pass my data from Component A to Component B in order to make an API call for the table it will render in Component C?

Comment: It depends where is the other component?

Comment: The other component is in the same folder. Basically the other component will use the data to make an API call and then produce a table with the data. @Mina

Comment: I see, but what I mean is where do you use this component, Is it a child of this component?

Comment: No the component that will render the table will be called in a third component that will display it. @Mina

Comment: Also, there is no event called `node_clicked`.

Comment: could you please provide full example of code.

Comment: @Mina it's a D3 diagram, the node_clicked is working, I am storing it in a variable I am just not sure how to pass it to the other component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing data from one component ( A ) to ANOTHER COMPONENT ( B ), will depend on where you use the B component.

If component B is a direct child component of component A.

You can easily pass data by [`props`](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html).

If component B is a deep child component of component A.

You can use [`inject/provide`](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html)

If component B is a parent of component A.

You can [`emit an event`](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html)

If component A and component B are used in different places in the code base.

You can create your own [`state management store`](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html) or you can use a library like [`Vuex`](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html)

Comment: Lets say Component A has data to provide to Component B and Component B will be used/rendered in Component C. How would you go about this? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is component `C` has a relation with component `A`?

Comment: yes it does, Component A creates a diagram that is shown in component C but I am using Component B to render a table when a user selects a node on that D3 diagram.

Comment: I suggest you use a state management [`Vuex`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) library to control your state in different components easily.