# Dynamic rendering of Iframe in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, iframe, nuxt.js, vuejs3

I am using vue.js and nuxt in my setup. I am trying to dynamically render my Iframe with a computed property based on a condition. The computed property is called in a different component. Based on my console.log I think there's no issue in my call. Even if videoRemoved should dynamically be false the div holding the Iframe is still rendered(Vue has had some problems with the Iframe in the past that's why my v-if is in the div. I feel like it has to do with vues dynamic rendering. Every possible hint is deeply appreciated.

```
<template>
    <div v-if="videoRemoved" class="relative w-full max-w-screen-lg mx-4 aspect-video">
        <iframe
          ref="videoPlayer"
          :src="item.src"
          title="Videoplayer"
          frameborder="0"
          allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-    picture"
          allowfullscreen
          class="absolute inset-0 w-full h-full"
        />
    </div>
  </template>
  
  <script>
import { nextTick } from 'vue';

export default {
  name: 'LightboxVideo',
    props: {
    item: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => null,
    },
  },
    computed: {
    videoRemoved( boolean) {
        if (boolean) {
            console.log(true)
            return true
        } else {
            console.log(false)
            return false 
        }
    },
}}
</script>

Method call in the lightbox component

<script>
import { Carousel, Slide } from 'vue3-carousel'
import LightboxVideo from '@/components/lightbox/video.vue'

export default {
    name: 'UiLightbox',

    components: {
        Carousel,
        Slide,
    },

    props: {
        items: {
            type: Array,
            default: () => [],
        },
    },

    data() {
        return {
            open: false,
            currentIndex: 0,
            carouselSettings: {
                itemsToShow: 1,
                itemsToScroll: 1,
                wrapAround: true,
                snapAlign: 'center',
            },
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
            if (e.key === 'Escape') {
                this.open = false
            }
        })

        // prev item on left arrow
        document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
            if (e.key === 'ArrowLeft') {
                this.prevItem()
            }
        })

        // next item on right arrow
        document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
            if (e.key === 'ArrowRight') {
                this.nextItem()
            }
        })
    },

    watch: {
        open: {
            handler(val) {
                if (val) {
                    // document && document.body.classList.add('overflow-hidden')

                    this.$nextTick(() => {
                        this.init()
                    })
                } else {
                    // document && document.body.classList.remove('overflow-hidden')
                }
            },
            immediate: true,
        },
    },

    methods: {
        init() {
            this.$refs.carousel.restartCarousel()
        },

        prevItem() {
            this.$refs.carousel.prev()
        },

        nextItem() {
            this.$refs.carousel.next()
        },

        openLightbox() {
            this.open = true
            this.startVideo()
        },

        closeLightbox() {
            this.open = false
            this.stopVideo()
        },
        stopVideo() {
            LightboxVideo.computed.videoRemoved(false)
        },
        startVideo() {
            LightboxVideo.computed.videoRemoved(true)
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: *Even if videoRemoved should be false* - the word "should" is doing the heavy lifting here... Have a look at [how to pass data between components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73533423/passing-data-between-vue-components)

Comment: you don't need a computed function for that. just created the 'videoRemoved' variable inside your component data. and change the value inside your methods.

Comment: I tried having videoRemoved as data and change them inside my methods at first changed to computed property because it didnt work

Comment: @MoritzRingler so I am trying to pass data from a Parent to its child component so I should use props right?

Comment: Yes. Have a look at the [Vue documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#passing-propsl), it probably has the best explanation you can get

Comment: OMG using passing it as a prop worked vielen herzlichen Dank Moritz!

Answer (score 0):

I had to pass the data through props since it's passed from the parent to the child component. As described here in the Vue documentation:
https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#passing-props